# How to test that a model is invalid without data when that date is required in after_initialize callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a class `Foo` that `belongs_to` `Bar`.

In `Foo` I have an `after_initialize` callback set up that calculates several values for its columns based on the `Bar` that it is initialized with.

In my specs I want to test that `Foo` is invalid without a `Bar`. The problem I am running into is that when I instantiate `Foo` without a `Bar`, the `after_initialize` callback runs and tries to access the `Bar`, which throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I test validations, I use [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to build a valid object first, change it to test various validation cases.

In your case, you could build foo with a valid bar:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    bar
  end
end
```

Then test removing the bar:

```
let(:foo){ build :foo }
…
it "should be invalid without bar" do
  foo.bar = nil
  expect(foo).to be_invalid
  expect(foo.errors.messages[:bar]).to eq "can't be blank"
end
```